# Object of objects JSON response from Django backend to React-Redux frontend

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, serialization

This is the response from Django when making axios api call in the frontend (array of JSON objects).

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "How to create a django-react app",
        "body": "You should first do this stuff and that"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "How to connect django with react",
        "body": "Get this and that stuff"
    }
]
```

But this is the response that I want (JSON object of JSON objects).
Is a Python dictionary the same as a Javascript object or Hashmap?
Is there some kind of middleware I can use to convert the shape?
Is this a job that the `serializers.py` needs to do or the `views.py`? How can I change the response from an array of objects to an object or objects?

```
{
    1: {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "How to create a django-react app",
        "body": "You should first do this stuff and that"
    },
    5: {
        "id": 5,
        "title": "How to connect django with react",
        "body": "Get this and that stuff"
    }
}
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class ArticleViewSet(ViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(ArticleViewSet.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        article = get_object_or_404(ArticleViewSet.queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(article, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to build a dictionary in the `ArticleViewSet`'s `list` method:

```
class ArticleViewSet(ViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(ArticleViewSet.queryset, many=True)
        return Response({article['id']: article for article in serializer.data})

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        # ...
```